# Subset list with vector of indices

Tags: r, list, vector, subset

Given vector `foo`, how is it possible to subset list `bar` where so that the indices of `bar` matches `foo` ?

```
bar
[[1]]
 [1] "eney"       "e  e"       "sonalisada" "ahorro"     "sio"        "a  ene"     "a"          "ra"         "m"          "ahorro"     ""           "d"          "cre"        "genericos" 
[15] "atención"   "calidad"    "servicio"   "ine"        "iuibue tes" "yrroa"      "su salud"   "ofertas"    "mvil ares"  "u"   

foo
[1]  8 15 17 20 22
```

The output should look like

```
[8] "ra"  [15] "atención"  [17] "servicio"  [20] "yrroa" [22] "ofertas"
```

The following method does not work, what is the correct way to do this?

```
which(bar[[1]] == foo)
```

The data:

```
dput(foo)
c(8L, 15L, 17L, 20L, 22L)

dput(bar)
list(c("eney", "e  e", "sonalisada", "ahorro", "sio", "a  ene", 
"a", "ra", "m", "ahorro", "", "d", "cre", "genericos", "atención", 
"calidad", "servicio", "ine", "iuibue tes", "yrroa", "su salud", 
"ofertas", "mvil ares", "u"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bar` is a list and if you have list of only length 1 you can either do :

```
bar[[1]][foo]
#[1] "ra"       "atención" "servicio" "yrroa"    "ofertas"
```

Or

```
unlist(bar)[foo]
```

If list is of length greater than 1 and you want to get `foo` values from each you can use `lapply`

```
lapply(bar, `[`, foo)
#Or
#sapply(bar, `[`, foo)
```